# Anführungszeichen in Verbindung mit dem Verb »bezeichnen«

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Ich schreibe gerade eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit und muss dabei hin und wieder Fachbegriffe kurz erläutern. Eine typische Konstruktion dafür geht so:

> Bei diesem Ansatz geht man zunächst von der Gegenhypothese aus, welche als Nullhypothese bezeichnet wird.

Erfordert das Verb *bezeichnen* hier Anführungszeichen um das Wort *Nullhypothese?* Mein Gefühl sagt mir ja, aber ich konnte keine Belege dafür finden.

Comment: Siehe hier: http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/zeichensetzung/anfuhrungszeichen.php.

Comment: Die Anführungszeichen sind spätestens ein bisschen unbeliebt, seit die "DDR" jahrzehntelang in der "Bild" zwischen zweien leben musste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Duden-Regel 8,1:](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/anfuehrungszeichen)

> Anführungszeichen **können** vor und hinter Wörtern oder Textstücken
>   stehen, die hervorgehoben werden sollen.
>
> Dazu gehören:
>
> 1. Wörter oder Wortgruppen (z. B. Sprichwörter, Äußerungen), über die man eine Aussage machen will:
>
>    - In dem Wort „Triathlon“ steckt das griechische „tri-“ (drei).

Es bleibt also dir überlassen.

In deinem speziellen Fall halte ich Anführungszeichen für nicht erforderlich, würde das *»welche«* allerdings durch *»die«* ersetzen.

Answer (score 12):

In einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit sind Anführungszeichen allein dazu da, um anzuführen, dass das, was in Anführungszeichen steht, ein direktes Zitat ist.

> Mustermann (2017) schreibt, dass „die Nullhypothese bei einem Alphakriterium von 0,01 abgelehnt werden“ muss. Musterfrau (2017) wendet allerdings ein, dass „[ü]ber die Daten von Mustermann [...] keine Aussage getroffen werden [kann], da die Daten sehr verrauscht waren.“

Was du möchtest, ist einen Begriff auszeichnen. Sinn und Zweck des Auszeichnens ist es, dem Leser beim Überfliegen des Textes das Auffinden der ausgezeichneten Stellen zu erleichtern. Würde man auch dafür Anführungszeichen verwenden, so geriete der Leser bei jedem Direktzitat ins Stocken; umgekehrt bliebe er auf der Suche nach Direktzitaten bei jeder Auszeichnung hängen.

Deshalb verwendet man für Auszeichnungen in der Regel kursive Schrift.

> ... dies wird als *Nullhypothese* bezeichnet.

Aber Achtung: In der Mathematik ist es üblich, dass der gesamte Körper einer Definitionen kursiv gesetzt wird. In diesem Fall ist das, was ausgezeichnet werden soll, aufrecht zu schreiben.

> **Definition (Nullhypothese)** *Eine* Nullhypothese *ist eine Gegenhypothese, bei der ...*

Gelegentlich wird für das Auszeichnen auch Fettdruck verwendet. Aber das ist eher zu vermeiden, vor allem wenn es viele Auszeichnungen gibt, da sonst das Schriftbild unruhig wird.